# asp.net login form sometimes returns to itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I encountered a strange error in 1 installation of our asp.net application (MVC 4, .net 4.0). Everything works fine for all other installations on test-machines.

The application start off with a login form. When the login is valid, the user is directed to the main page.

However, on that one system, the login form has a ~ 70% chance to do pretty much nothing. If username/password are correct, the server where IIS is running is at 99% CPU usage and also consumes a lot of RAM for 10-20 seconds. Then, the login form is reset (empty username/password), but no redirection to the main page. No error is logged or shown.

If username/password are incorrect, the Login form instantly shows the corresponding error message.

Where should i start looking for error?

This is the LogOn Method in the LogOn Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    _logger.LogDebug("LogOn_p: Start => " + model);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {

            _logger.LogInfo("LogOn_p: login start => " + model + ", returnUrl: " + returnUrl);

            // < Here the login is confirmed (or not) >

            _logger.LogInfo("LogOn_p: login success");

            // Navigate to the previous page if given.
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            else
                // Navigate to the main page.
                return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("LogOn_p: ERROR => " + ex);
        }

        // FAILED.
        _logger.LogInfo("LogOn_p: login failed");
        model.Controller = this;
        model.Initialize();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Try adding "time" to the log so you know which block of code takes more time

Comment: Good idea. However, the log methods prepend DateTime :-) I'm still adding more and more Log messages to find out where it goes wrong... the Exception is not thrown for example... So it should call "RedirectToAction" (i cannot use debugger)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Our web application uses glimpse, which is usually deactivated when installing on a non-developer system. After deactivating the logging of glimpse in Web.config, even though it seemed redundant, fixed the error on that one system.